# UPDATE RECORDS USING PHP LOOP

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update data in my database using php loop.

I have tried updating data, but it only updates the last record in my list and returns all the records as null/zero.

```
// attempting to update data
$rcount_student_lists = mysqli_query($mysqli, $count_student_lists);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rcount_student_lists))
    $student_count_count = $row2['0'];

for ($id = 1; $id <=$student_count_count; $id++)
{  
    $sql = "UPDATE exam_data SET score_s = '".${'dd_'.$id}."' WHERE exam_name_s = '".$one."'";
}

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo juuhead("DETAILS UPDATED SUCCESFULLY");
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

I would want it to update all the records in the column score_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating the SQL string in a loop:

```
for ($id = 1; $id <=$student_count_count; $id++)
{  
    $sql = ...;
}
```

But you're only executing it once, because this is outside the loop:

```
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
```

Move the query command inside the loop:

```
for ($id = 1; $id <=$student_count_count; $id++)
{  
    $sql = ...
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

You're also missing braces on your while loop:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rcount_student_lists))
$student_count_count = $row2['0'];
```

Without braces, the while only loops the one line following it. To loop over more than one line, you need to wrap the lines in braces:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rcount_student_lists))
{
    $student_count_count = $row2['0'];
    for ($id = 1; $id <=$student_count_count; $id++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: This loops the response and only updates the last record.

Comment: Ah, noticed another error and updated the response.

Comment: Note, you'll benefit greatly from proper indentation. It's much harder to see where loops are broken if every line starts on the first column.

Comment: I figured it out